# Is it possible to get data from a ZMQ socket, that is about to be closed?

Tags: javascript, sockets, zeromq

I need to implement a bit extension of ZMQ, in which a '**`REQ`**' socket has and extra method called "**`.request()`**".

This method can recieve more than 1 parameter and ( here I have the problem ) if the first parameter is **0**, **`.request( 0, ... )`** just sends the message, otherwise it has to wait 10 seconds, and if in this time I have no response or error, I have to **`.close()`** the socket and open it again.

**So, the question is**: How can I know in my extension of ZMQ, ***where*** the client is connected to be able to reconnect ***there*** my new socket?

( I need to use promises too, this is why in the code appears "**`Q.deffer()`**" and all these things )

```
var zmq = require('./pzmq');
var rq = zmq.socket('req');
var counter=0;
function onSuccess(msg) {
    console.log('Response: '+msg);
    console.log(msg instanceof Array);
}

function onError(err) {
    console.log('Error: '+err);
}
rq.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:8888');
console.log(rq.indentity);

// The "Hello" string is sent every second

reply = rq.request(0, counter++,4);
reply.then(onSuccess,onError);
```

And here I have my little extension of ZMQ, called **`pzmq`**:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var Q = require('bluebird');

// Save the original socket method, we need it
var socket = zmq.socket;

// Create and store the wrapper method
zmq.socket = function(kind) {

    // it uses the original method anyways, to get a zmq socket
    var so = socket.call(zmq, kind);

    if (kind == 'req') {
        // if a 'req' socket is requested, then we add the extra method 2
        so.request = request;
    }
    return so;
};


function request() {
    var d = Q.defer();
    var that = this; 

    var onResponse = function () {
        console.log(arguments instanceof Array);
        d.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); 
        that.removeListener('error', onError);  
    };
    var onError = function (e) {
        d.reject(e);
        that.removeListener('message', onResponse); 
    };

    this.once('message', onResponse); // set up the handler for only one message
    this.once('error', onError);      // set up the handler for only one

    var argumentos = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var tiempo = argumentos[0];
    if (tiempo==0){
        this.send(argumentos);
    }else{
        //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }

    return d.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short: No.

### Long: Yes.

ZeroMQ library allows you to setup a scaleable messaging framework, designed as per your needs. Flexibility thereof is the maxim, and your design and imagination boundaries are the principal limits.

In case you need to `.close()` / re-open a ZMQ-socket, your application shall create it's own, state-full Connection Manager, that is both aware & responsible for transport-class settings, connection-addressing, archetype-selection and last but not least, the proper timing of `.connect()` / `.bind()` / ev. re-subscribe phases.

Seems that it sounds complicated? Yes, it is, nevertheless there is no "cheap-shortcut". The low-level library methods & attributes simply cannot "guess" your outer-world rules and priorities, so it is your turn to specify + analyse + design + test/validate what comes as a mandatory feature / behaviour on the application layer.

ZMQ will help you execute the "rest".